# How to download and install package automatically if required in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, github, package, tidyverse

How can I download and install this [packages](https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggsankey) from GitHub automatically, if it is not installed in RStudio?

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
library(ggsankey)
```

Comment: By using exactly what you have there inside a `if (isFALSE(requireNamespace("ggsankey", quietly=TRUE)) { ... }` block.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, why the `isFALSE`? I haven't run into a situation where `requireNamespace` returns anything other than `logical`. (Or is this just defensive-programming applied in general, not strictly necessary here?)

Comment: Not strictly needed but I am getting used to the more assertive nature of `isFALSE(..)` and `isTRUE(...)` which make very clear on what result action is required, and which are very robust to NAs and side effect.  But as you astutely note, it is candy here and could be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `p_load_gh()` from `pacman` package

```r
pacman::p_load_gh("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
```

this will check if `ggsankey` is installed, if not it will install it and then load the package.

Comment: I didn't downvote this but maybe it was because it only works if pacman is already installed and the whole point of this is to automatically install a package without prerequisites.

Comment: oh, but as OP asked, he needs to install a package from GitHub automatically if it is not installed, and at a minimum, he needs either `{remotes}` or `{devtools}` to do that since there's no base function that installs packages from Github as far as I know. So he needs to install at least one package, either `{remotes}`, `{devtools}` or even `{pacman}` before he proceeds on.  Right ? @G.Grothendieck

Comment: So in that sense, this solution should also be valid, right? I am just trying to understand if there's any problem with this approach or is this approach irrelevant to this question or anything ? @G.Grothendieck

Comment: It is not automatic so the solution is invalid.  pacman needs to be installed manually.  To fix this the solution would need to provide code to automatically install pacman if not already installed.

Comment: Oh, ok I understand. But I was trying to say that, he could have installed `{pacman}` like he did install `remotes`, and then using function `pacman` should be easier than writing code manually. But, anyway I understand your point. Thanks for you comments @G.Grothendieck

Comment: If the issue is that is pacman might not be preinstalled, then put:
```if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")``` before `pacman::p_load_gh("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
`

Answer (score 0):

Load ggsankey or if not installed load remotes or if that is not installed then install it and then use it to install and load ggsankey.   Omit `quietly=TRUE` if you would prefer to see the warning messages.  These instructions do not depend on RStudio and should work more generally.

Note that this installs packages but not external programs such as R itself and on Windows Rtools. The latter is needed on Windows for packages with C/C++ code.  Also if the user is using an old version of R any package dependencies may be only available on CRAN in source form increasing the likelihood that they need Rtools on Windows.  Thus the instructions should specify that the latest version of R be used and that on Windows Rtools be installed.  Both these are easy to install because they have automated installers.

```
if (!require("ggsankey", quietly = TRUE)) {
  if (!requireNamespace("remotes", quietly = TRUE)) {
    install.packages("remotes")
  }
  remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey",
    dependencies = TRUE, upgrade = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
  library("ggsankey")
}
```

That said it seems dangerous to be automatically installing software.  Suggest you just give them instructions on installing the software and loading it explaining how to install latest version of R and Rtools on Windows first.

```
# From within R install ggsankey R package.
# Only needs to be done once.

install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey",
    dependencies = TRUE, upgrade = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)

# load ggsankey - needs to be done in every new R session using it

library(ggsankey)
```

Comment: I forget the reasons why but the powers-that-be recommended switching to `requireNamespace()` for such tests of 'is it installed or not' a couple of years ago and it has served me well.

Comment: That would not put it on the search path but the question puts ggsankey on the search path in any case so it is just a matter of whether remotes is put on the search path in the case that it is used and doing so has no real downside.  If you want to keep it off the search path then, sure, use `requireNamespace` or `detach` it afterwards.

Comment: I think you edited your answer since I asked, and the current use of _test and load_ is clearer.

Comment: I have added requireNamespace for remotes.  For ggsankey the question puts it on the search path so in that case I left it as is.